# I want to draw class diagram, but I don't know how to put server and database inside?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I just started to draw class diagram, I think it is based on 3-tie architecture. I have mobile application, servers, database, and web interface.

But I do not know if it should put the server in? I just want to write a high-level one.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 8):

A server or database doesn't go into a class diagram. A class diagram, at the highest level, shows the classes and their relationships with each other. Adding more detail would first indicate public members, and even more detail would indicate private members of the class. You may show classes that interact with the database (your data model, as an example), but you wouldn't actually show a database.

A [deployment diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram) would show which pieces of your system reside on what physical nodes. For example, you could have a "mobile application" node (which may be further detailed by other diagrams) that would reside on types of mobile devices, a web application that resides on web servers, and linkages between web servers and database servers.

A [component diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram) could be used to indicate pieces that communicate with a database, as well.

Comment: If I would like to add interface to external sources, how can I do?

Comment: @user2137886 You typically don't do that in a class diagram. I would suggest researching component diagrams. You can start with the Wikipedia page I linked to - they have an example where they show an interface to an LDAP system and how that is represented.

Comment: Thanks, I am still wondering how to show classes interact with database. DO you have some links about this?

Comment: @user2137886 Please read my answer, some of the Wikipedia pages I linked to, and perform some additional research based on what you read. **Class diagrams do not show interaction with databases**, since databases aren't classes. Class diagrams show relationships between classes. Other diagram types exist (UML alone has 14 diagram types, and there are other modeling notations as well) for this type of behavior.